# All purchases have been downloaded for this Apple ID

Tags: itunes, apple-id, appletv

When I make purchases from my Apple TV it won't automatically download to iTunes on my Mac Mini.

1. All software is up to date via the current versions available from the App store.
2. I have reset the Apple TV and resetup the devices.
3. Created new user on Mac Mini.
4. Signed into iTunes on the New account and the same problem exists.
5. Checked for available downloads via the "Store" option and get a message : "All purchases have been downloaded for this Apple ID."

I suspect that the issue can be directly related to the Apple ID and will test with a Different ID tonight. I hope there is someone else who experienced the same issue that can assist.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to purchase? Also make sure you are buying and not renting, as movies rented on Apple TV [cannot be transferred](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201611) to another device.

Comment: I am buying movies and series. I am positive I am not renting. All I am trying to do is make purchases on my Apple TV and have it automatically download to my iTunes on my Mac Mini.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at this time. On iTunes for Windows, as of version 12.2, you can choose to automatically download all music, books, and apps. On iTunes for Mac, you can automatically download music and apps; and defer to the iBooks app to automatically download books. Movies, however, is not available on either platform.

You can automate it using Automator, however. Your Automator flow would look like this: Open iTunes, click Movies, My Movies, then press Command–A, Right-click on the selection, and choosing Make available offline, close the iTunes window. (Based on [this](https://www.aeyoun.com/how-to/redownload-all-itunes-purchases.html).) You would then have to schedule the Automator flow to run at 02 am every night or something. Doable, but inelegant.